# Port Forwarding to local network computer while it is connected to a VPN

Tags: networking, router, vpn, port-forwarding

So I have a Linux Machine on my local network that is connected to a VPN.

I have setup port forwarding on my router to route all traffic for that computers ip and with port `app_port` to that computer.

From within my local network I can access a web application on that computer at `ip_address:app_port` with no problem, even when that computer is connected to its VPN.

When I try to access that same computer at `my_external_ip:app_port`, while its connected to VPN, I get nothing.

1. Why can't I reach the computer?

I would expect that the data hits my router and since I am port forwarding all traffic for that port and ip to that computer (and since I can reach it with a local computer), i would expect it to work.

2. Any ways around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you add a specific route via VPN on your local PC and default gateway via router, external_ip:port should work. Some stateful firewall can block assymetric routing